# Python Flask not showing image

Tags: python, opencv, object, flask, computer-vision

I have a file to put all my algorithms for image recognition, right now it's just an empty frame to test.
It's called algorithms.py

```
import cv2
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

class algorithms:
    def raw_image(caller):
        while True:
            success, frame = camera.read()
            if not success:
                print("Error reading from camera")
            frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)  #mirror image vertically
            
            caller.output(frame)
```

If I try to set up a web server using flask, it's not working as I tried here. The server is running as shown in the console output, but I'm unable to connect to it using the browser.

```
from algorithms import algorithms
from flask import Flask, Response
import cv2


class server:
    def output(self, frame):
        ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        frame = buffer.tobytes()

        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')


    def web(self):
        app = Flask(__name__)
        @app.route('/')
        def video_feed():
            return Response(algorithms.raw_image(self), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)


server().web()
```

What am I missing?

When I run this file with the `cv2.imshow` it works fine, like here

```
from algorithms import algorithms
import cv2

class window:
    def output(self, frame):
            cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
            #exit
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                exit()

    def start(self):
        algorithms.raw_image(self)



window().start()
```

Comment: `algorythms.raw_image(self)` never returns.

Comment: It's designed to call the output function using `caller.output(frame)` in the loop.

Comment: `caller.output(frame)` does a yeild but that value is yielded back to `raw_image()` and discarded. I guess you might try `yield from caller.output(frame)` and see what that does for you.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `caller.output(frame)` to `yield caller.output(frame)` in algorithms and `yield (b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')` to `return (b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')` made a stream visible.